# Battleship with Python

Tags: python

Here I've some difficulties with my program ... I tried everything but nothing works ...

Here is my code:

```
import random

XBateau_un_joueur = 0
YBateau_un_joueur = 0
XBateau_deux_joueur = 1
YBateau_deux_joueur = 1
XBateau_un_IA = 0
YBateau_un_IA = 0
XBateau_deux_IA = 1
YBateau_deux_IA = 1

def Grille(): #définition du tableau qui servira de grille
    tableau_joueur = [(0,)*taille]*taille

    for i in range(taille):
        tableau_joueur[i] = list(tableau_joueur[i])
    tableau_joueur[XBateau_deux_joueur][YBateau_deux_joueur] = 1
    tableau_joueur[XBateau_un_joueur][YBateau_un_joueur] = 1

   if XBateau_un_joueur == XBateau_deux_joueur and YBateau_un_joueur == YBateau_deux_joueur :
        XBateau_deux_joueur = XBateau_deux_joueur + 1
        YBateau_deux_joueur = YBateau_deux_joueur + 1

        if XBateau_deux_joueur > taille - 1 :
           XBateau_deux_joueur = XBateau_deux_joueur - 2

        if YBateau_deux_joueur > taille - 1 :
           YBateau_deux_joueur = YBateau_deux_joueur - 2

    tableau_IA = [(0,)*taille]*taille

    for j in range(taille):
        tableau_IA[j] = list(tableau_IA[j])
    tableau_IA[XBateau_un_IA][YBateau_deux_IA] = 1
    tableau_IA[XBateau_deux_IA][YBateau_deux_IA] = 1

    if XBateau_un_IA and YBateau_un_IA == XBateau_deux_IA and YBateau_deux_IA :
        XBateau_deux_IA = XBateau_deux_IA + 1
        YBateau_deux_IA = YBateau_deux_IA + 1

        if XBateau_deux_IA > taille - 1 :
           XBateau_deux_IA = XBateau_deux_IA - 2

        if YBateau_deux_joueur > taille - 1 :
           YBateau_deux_IA = YBateau_deux_IA - 2

    print tableau_joueur
    print tableau_IA

def tour_IA():
    compteur_de_point_IA = 0

    for tour_IA in range (0, 3):

        print "L'ennemi nous attaque Capitain !"
        x = int(random.randint(0, taille - 1))
        y = int(random.randint(0, taille - 1))

        if ((x == XBateau_un_joueur) and (y == YBateau_un_joueur)) or ((x == XBateau_deux_joueur) and (y == YBateau_deux_joueur)) :
            compteur_de_point_IA = compteur_de_point_IA + 8
            print "Arg ! Cette raclure de fond de calle nous a coulé en vaisseau... prenez garde !"

        else:

           if (x == XBateau_un_joueur) or (y == YBateau_un_joueur) or (x == XBateau_deux_joueur) or (y == YBateau_deux_joueur) :
                compteur_de_point_IA = compteur_de_point_IA + 1
                print "nous sommes en vue de l'ennemi Cap'tain ! Faite attention !"

            else:
                print "A l'eau ! Il nous a raté !"
    print "Voici les points marqué par l'ennemis :", compteur_de_point_IA

    # tour du joueur IRL

def tour_joueur():
    list_resultat = []
    List_tot = []
    print " C'est à vous d'attaquer"

    for tour_joueur in range (0, 3):
        compteur_de_point_joueur = 0
        print "En attente des ordres, lattitude du tir mon capitain ?"
        print "(colone)"
        x = int(input())
        print "longitude du tir ?"
        print "(ligne)"
        y = int(input())

        if ((x == XBateau_un_IA) and (y == YBateau_un_IA)) or ((x == XBateau_deux_IA) and (y == YBateau_deux_IA)) :
            compteur_de_point_joueur = compteur_de_point_joueur + 8
            print "Aarrrr ! Navire ennemi envoyé par le fond Cap'tain!"
            print "Vous marqué 8 points supplémentaires !! Bien joué!"

    else:

          if (x == XBateau_un_IA) or (y == YBateau_un_IA) or (x == XBateau_deux_IA) or (y == YBateau_deux_IA):
            compteur_de_point_joueur = compteur_de_point_joueur + 1
            print "L'ennemis est en vue ! Pas mal boucanier !"
            print "Vous marqué 1 point supplémentaire !!"

          else:
            print "Mille sabords !!! Raté !!! Recommencez marins d'eau douce !"
        print "Voici votre total de point marqué :", compteur_de_point_joueur
        print " "
        list_resultat.append(compteur_de_point_joueur)
        print list_resultat[0]
    print 



def nombre_de_joueur() :
    print "Combien de joueur êtes vous ?"
    nombre = int(input())
    print "Vent dans les voiles !! Vent dans les voiles !!"
    for k in range(0, nombre) :
        Grille()
        tour_joueur()
        print " "
        print " "
        tour_IA()




taille = int(input("Veuillez saisir la taille du champs de bataille matelot !"))

XBateau_un_joueur = random.randint(0, taille - 1)#bateau n°1 du joueur
YBateau_un_joueur = random.randint(0, taille - 1)
XBateau_deux_joueur = random.randint(0, taille - 1)#bateau n°2 du joueur
YBateau_deux_joueur = random.randint(0, taille - 1)

XBateau_un_IA = random.randint(0, taille - 1)#bateau n°1 de l'IA
YBateau_un_IA = random.randint(0, taille - 1)
XBateau_deux_IA = random.randint(0, taille - 1)#bateau n°2 de l'IA
YBateau_deux_IA = random.randint(0, taille - 1)


nombre_de_joueur()
```

And this is the shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marion\Documents\Marion\Work\ISN\BatailleNavale2.py", line 138, in <module>
    nombre_de_joueur()
  File "C:\Users\Marion\Documents\Marion\Work\ISN\BatailleNavale2.py", line 116, in nombre_de_joueur
    Grille()
  File "C:\Users\Marion\Documents\Marion\Work\ISN\BatailleNavale2.py", line 17, in Grille
    tableau_joueur[XBateau_deux_joueur][YBateau_deux_joueur] = 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'XBateau_deux_joueur' referenced before assignment
```

So if you have an idea..

PS : Sorry if my english is bad... I'm french!

Comment: It looks like `XBateau_deux_joueur` doesn't exist.

Comment: `XBateau_deux_joueur = XBateau_deux_joueur + 1` -> `XBateau_deux_joueur += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to the variable here:

```
XBateau_deux_joueur = XBateau_deux_joueur + 1
```

Python sees this assignment within your function and then, as a result, understands this variable within a local, rather than a global, scope. So the variable does not refer to the global variable that you probably think it should refer to. Thus when you reference the local variable here:

```
tableau_joueur[XBateau_deux_joueur][YBateau_deux_joueur] = 1
```

Python has never seen this variable before within the local scope of the function. The name is unbound, and Python throws an error. If you want to refer to the global variable instead, try this: before any reference to the variable, declare it as a global variable (within the function):

```
def Grille(): #définition du tableau qui servira de grille
    global XBateau_deux_joueur
    . . .
```

Any time you assign a value to a variable within a function, Python will assume that the variable is local in scope throughout the entire function unless told otherwise.

Comment: I've this now... T_T

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marion\Documents\Marion\Work\ISN\BatailleNavale2.py", line 138, in <module>
    nombre_de_joueur()
  File "C:\Users\Marion\Documents\Marion\Work\ISN\BatailleNavale2.py", line 116, in nombre_de_joueur
    Grille()
  File "C:\Users\Marion\Documents\Marion\Work\ISN\BatailleNavale2.py", line 17, in Grille
    tableau_joueur[XBateau_deux_joueur][YBateau_deux_joueur] = 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'XBateau_deux_joueur' referenced before assignment

But thanks!!^^